# while sending mail from windows service embedded image in mail comes blank c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, webbrowser-control, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to make a windows service that will send mailer automatically everyday. I'm using [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) for sending mails from exchange server.

In timers elapsed event I'm calling all the processing for sending mails and all.

I need to send the embedded image in the mailers and that image need to be generated on the fly from the some Html. So I used the webbrowser control and ran it as a separate thread.

First-Approach : I tried to save the image in local system and used it as an inline attachment

Second-Approach : I tried to save the image in memory stream and then used that memory stream in attachment.

In both the scenarios when I run this windows service application in debug mode and execute line by line statement by pressing F11 then everything works fine.
I mean the image comes in that case.

But the moment I run the application as windows service mailers are sent but the image comes blank. I tried to attach a pre existing image then It did work fine.

But When the same image is generated and use it either in memory stream or by saving it on local system and then using it as an attachment, in that case Image comes blank in the mail.

[Here is the link for sending out the mails using EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532564(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Here is the code for running webbrowser control in separate thread

```
private static void StartBrowser(string htmlSource)
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted +=
            webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        webBrowser.DocumentText = source;
        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

static void 
    webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(
    object sender, 
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    using (Bitmap bitmap = 
        new Bitmap(
            webBrowser.Width, 
            webBrowser.Height))
    {
        webBrowser
            .DrawToBitmap(
            bitmap, 
            new System.Drawing
                .Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
        bitmap.Save(@"filename.jpg", 
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Please help me. I'm stuck and browsed a lot of things but couldn't figure out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there someone who can help me out with this ?